Need Help with Efficient Map Design for GTA-Style Open World in Unity
I’m currently working on a GTA-style open-world game in Unity and modeling the map. The map is roughly the size of Portland from GTA 3. I’ve run into some challenges with my workflow and topology and would appreciate any advice or tips you might have.
Here’s how I currently work:

I start by gathering reference images from Google Maps.
I import these references and create a plane.
Using the reference, I extrude the plane to shape the roads.

This works fine at first, but as the map grows, the topology starts to get really messy (see attached images).
Next, I select the road edges (Alt + Shift) and extrude them to create sidewalks. Finally, I plan to add the ground (grass/concrete, etc.) around it. But this part gets very tricky because of how messy the topology has become.
I’m trying to keep the polygon count low for performance reasons. I’ve watched countless tutorials on creating roads, but most of them result in high-poly roads that seem like they’d need an RTX 4090 to render properly.
Does anyone have tips or tricks to share? Am I going about this the wrong way? I’m especially interested in workflows that keep topology clean and performance-friendly for Unity.



Hello and welcome. This question is not a very good fit for our site. We are more geared towards focused technical question about Blender itself, rather that general artistic advice and discussion. This is probably better suited for Blender Artists Forum. Some general advice: Don't try to model everything from a single continuous gigantic mesh
